# How to show current year in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a function I can use to show the current year in a view? I have tried

```
<%= Time.now  %>
```

to try and show the time but this does not work for me.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

```
<%= Time.current.year %>
```

http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_ruby/datesandtimes.html

Answer (score 50):

I'd rather use Date class to get year than Time class (if you only need the Date, you don't need to consider hours, minutes and seconds).

```
<%= Date.today.year %>
```

c.f. http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-today

Answer (score 47):

I think the best way to get the current year **considering application timezone** is:

```
Date.current.year
```

Comment: Agreed. Also, `Date.current` is the same as `Time.zone.today` if `config.time_zone` is set.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Date.current is the most appropriate.

Answer (score 18):

I like to use:

```
Time.zone.now.year
```

This takes into account the current timezone (incase you have overridden it for a particular user).

Answer (score 9):

Despite that it has already been answered, I thought it might come handy for those who want to look at benchmark results for all the suggested solutions.

```ruby
require 'benchmark'

n = 500000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { n.times do ; Date.today.year; end }
  x.report { n.times do ; Date.current.year; end }
  x.report { n.times do ; Time.current.year; end }
  x.report { n.times do ; Time.zone.now.year; end }
end

    user     system      total        real
0.680000   0.030000   0.710000 (  0.709078)
2.730000   0.010000   2.740000 (  2.735085)
3.340000   0.010000   3.350000 (  3.363586)
3.070000   0.000000   3.070000 (  3.082388)
```

Now, it may perhaps seem over the top for something as simple as that, however, from a simple optimisation perspective for a high throughput application, I will consider using `Date.today.year`

Said so, if your application is Time Zone sensitive, perhaps `Date.current` or `Time.zone` based methods are your best bet.

Check out this wonderful [Railscast by Ryan on Time Zones](http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised)